# pdflatex not found while installing "R" software on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, latex, r

I am trying to install R software on Ubuntu 19.04, by compiling the installer on my system. Several libraries are missing, but I managed to install them all, apart from one called 'pdflatex'.

```
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/giulio/Desktop/r-base_3.6.1.orig/R-3.6.1/src/library'
'pdflatex' is needed to make vignettes but is missing on your system.
```

I didn't manage to find how to install on the web, could you help me with this issue?

Best
Giulio

Comment: Check this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112734/is-it-possible-to-install-only-the-required-latex-tool-pdflatex-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [`texlive-latex-base`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=disco&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=pdflatex) package, which provides this utility:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base
```

And also please note, that R is packaged in Ubuntu as `r-base` and `r-base-dev` packages (see [search results](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=r-base&searchon=names&suite=disco&section=all), you will get R 3.5.2). You do not need to compile R by yourself (usually).
If you need R 3.6 - use binary repository from [R-CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/#installation).